# Token-base matching with spaCy REGEX

Tags: python, regex, nlp, spacy

I'm newbie to spacy and I've read the docs about token-base matching. I've tried spaCy matcher using the REGEX but  I don't have any results.

When I use the re library to do the match it works though.

Am I doing something wrong in the code.

I'm trying to match the "accès'd" word

Thanks for your help

```
# REGEX
import re
text = u"accès'd est ferme aujpourd'hui"
pattern_re = re.compile("^acc?é?e?è?s?s?'?D" , re.I)
pattern_re.match(text)

# <re.Match object; span=(0, 7), match="accès'd">

# REGEX SPACY VERSION 1
import spacy
from spacy.matcher import Matcher
nlp = spacy.load("fr_core_news_sm")

pattern = [{'TEXT': {'REGEX' : "^acc?é?e?è?s?s?'?D"}}]
matcher = Matcher(nlp.vocab)
matcher.add('AccèsD' , None , pattern)


doc = nlp(text)

matches = matcher(doc)
for match_id, start , end in matches:
    match_string = nlp.vocab.strings[match_id]
    span = doc[start:end]
    print(match_id, match_string, start , end , span.text)

# NOTHING

# REGEX SPACY VERSION 2
import spacy
from spacy.matcher import Matcher
nlp = spacy.load("fr_core_news_sm")

accesd_flag = lambda text : bool(re.compile(r"^acc?é?e?è?s?s?'?D" , re.I).match(text))
IS_ACCESD = nlp.vocab.add_flag(accesd_flag)
pattern=  [{IS_ACCESD : True}]

matcher = Matcher(nlp.vocab)
matcher.add('AccèsD' , None , pattern)

doc = nlp(text)

matches = matcher(doc)
for match_id, start , end in matches:
    match_string = nlp.vocab.strings[match_id]
    span = doc[start:end]
    print(match_id, match_string, start , end , span.text)


# NOTHING
```

Comment: Why don't you make an `on_match` function instead of `None` then you can use it to help you debug

Answer (score 1):

Regex support for spacy was introduced in version 2.1.0

From [the website](https://spacy.io/usage/rule-based-matching)

> Versions before v2.1.0 don’t yet support the REGEX operator.

It might be related to this, since `REGEX` for the matcher will not be used otherwise

Otherwise, I believe the answer is related to not matching all contextual tokens. You should then just slightly modify the regex and use the `LOWER` matching attribute to capture the two token context.

```
text = u"accès'd est ferme aujpourd'hui"
pattern = [{"LOWER" : { "REGEX": "^acc?é?e?è?s?s?" }, {"LOWER": "d"}]
matcher = Matcher(nlp.vocab)
matcher.add("accesd", None, pattern) 
doc = nlp(text) 
matches = matcher(doc)
```

This is because you were using the `re.I` flag so the matcher will work in a case insensitive way by only reviewing the `LOWER` attribute

Comment: Hi Nathan, thanks for your reply. I’ve checked spaCy version and it’s the last one

Comment: Oh too bad, thought it could be that.

Comment: I think I found the source of the problem. IT's the spacy tokenizer who splits the text into ['accès', 'd', 'est', 'ferme', "aujpourd'", 'hui'] and this is why the regex does not give a match

Comment: Oh I see, that's right. I'll add an answer I believe shall work